# Match a word but not its inverse using [^] syntax

Tags: regex, scala, cucumber

I am trying to make a regex that *doesn't* match one word, but *does* match its reverse. For example, if the word I don't want to match is "no":

```
I am matching this word   // will pass
I am matching no word     // will not pass
I am matching on word     // will pass
I am matching that word   // will pass
```

The current regex I am using doesn't pass on the third example, because it is not matching any word with "n" or "o" in it:

```
^I am matching ([^no]*) word$
```

What is the best way to achieve this - ie, match on a word, not a collection of characters?

For context I am writing acceptance tests using Scala and Cucumber, which use Regex to match a feature file up with its corresponding stepdef. My real-world example is more complex, so I have simplified it here. Also, I know that I can just catch `(.*)` and handle what is in that capture group using a `case`/`match` block in Scala, but I am curious about how to do this with purely Regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to test the text you're about to match:

```
^I am matching (?!no\b)(?<CapturedWord>\w+) word$
```

`(?!no\b)` - This is a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It tests the next two characters. If they are "no" followed by a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), then the match fails. Anything else will pass. A lookahead does not actually capture those characters, so...

`(?<CapturedWord>\w+)` - ...we need to capture the characters in order to continue on with the rest of the test. I used a [named group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) because they're often easier to reference later on in code.

Answer (score 0):

An other solution consists to describe all words that aren't "on". Note that this solution isn't handy if you want to negate a long substring, but with several regex engines that don't have the lookahead feature, this is the only way:

```
^I am matching ([^\Wn]\w+|n[^\Wo]+|\w(?:\w{2,})?) word$
```

The two first branch of the alternation match in particular all 2 letters words that aren't "no", the last branch matches one letter and 3 or more letters words.